# Resolutions of configuration space of the projective line where the complement is of "Tate type"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, arithmetic-geometry, toric-varieties

I would like to find a nice compactification $X_n$ of $F(\mathbb P^1,n)$ (considered as a scheme over $\mathbb Z$), the $n$-fold configuration space of the projective line with the property that the $S_n$ action extends to an action of $X_n$ and moreover, for every subgroup $H \subset S_n$, there exists a resolution $X_{n,H} \to X_n/H$ such that the complement of $F(X,n)/H$ in $X_{n,H}$ is a simple normal crossings divisor such that the intersections of subsets of the divisors are all of *Tate type.*

We say that a smooth projective scheme $T/\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$ is of Tate type if the action of the Frobenius $\sigma_p$ on the 'etale cohomology of $T\otimes \overline{\mathbb F}_p$ has eigenvalues powers of $p$ in even degrees (and is $0$ in odd degrees). For instance, this follows if $T$ has an affine or toric stratification.

I believe that the maximal wonderful compactification has this property (a construction is given in Ulyanovs "[Polydiagonal compactifications of configuration spaces](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9904049.pdf)" but actually proving it seems involved and I am hoping it is already in the literature since this is quite a reasonable thing to wish for.

Comment: I think the Kontsevich moduli space $\overline{\mathcal M}_{0,n}(\mathbb P^1,1)$ of stable curves of genus $0$ with a degree $1$ map to $\mathbb P^1$ should have all these properties.

Comment: @WillSawin If I understand correctly, this moduli space is the same as the Fulton-Macpherson compactification (see the bottom of page 5, https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9608011). The stabilizers of the $S_n$ action on this compactification are solvable in general so it wasn't clear to me that singularities would be so nice. Do you have an idea for a compactification from the moduli perspective? It seems promising at first sight.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you also want the quotients by arbitrary subgroups $H$ to have simple normal crossings. How devious!

Comment: Actually, I am okay with a different resolution (of Tate type) for each H of X_n/H. Is this easier?

Comment: Certainly the quotient of $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,4}(\mathbb{P}^1,1)$ by the cyclic subgroup $H=\langle (12)(34)\rangle \subset S_4$ is not smooth.

Comment: @WillSawin  The compactification $\overline{M}_{0,n}(\mathbb{P}^1,[\mathbb{P}^1])$ is not a wonderful compactification, since the boundary divisor is not a strict normal crossings divisor.  This is also the "reason" behind my example above.  So perhaps the minimal wonderful blowing up of $\overline{M}_{0,n}(\mathbb{P}^1,[\mathbb{P}^1])$ *might* satisfy the OP's conditions (I do not know if it does, but it does eliminate my example).

Comment: @JasonStarr I am confused. Is the Kontsevich Moduli space in this case not exactly the Fulton-MacPherson compactification? I thought that was a wonderful compactification - is this wrong?

Comment: Oops, I forgot that your marked points are labelled.  I often work with the quotient by $S_n$ where the marked points are not labelled, and then the boundary divisor is irreducible, hence not simple normal crossings.  Sorry for the mistake!  Anyway, it does look like some choice of blowing up of the strata in the boundary stratification might give a compactification satisfying your conditions.